# Do LEGO stores sell bricks in bulk?

Tags: shopping, lego-store

I've seen these pictures of LEGO stores, but have been unable to work it out: Are they are plastic bubbles on the wall that you can dig youe hand into and buy LEGO bricks in bulk, or are they just for decoration? Do the high-street LEGO stores offer a bulk-brick-buy option, or do they just sell sets and games?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can indeed take bricks and purchase them. I've listed the main types of Pick-A-Brick in [this answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/1166/132):

> The LEGO retail outlets house a matrix of bins, each filled with a
>   certain type of brick. The bricks used tend be excess bricks from
>   LEGO's own factories and some bricks of the same kind may be included
>   in more than one bin. Bricks are packed into small or large plastic
>   cups, you pay for getting as many bricks as you can in one cup.

The top few rows of bins are generally just decorative, it would take a fully grown adult on a kickstool/ladder to reach the top bins.

Other products unique to LEGO retail stores include:

- [Exclusive and limited edition sets](http://shop.lego.com/en-GB/Exclusives-ByTheme?cn=245&d=100) (which can also be bought from Lego.com)
- You can build and buy minifigures which consist of torso, legs, head, helmet/headpiece and accessory.
- Events, such as the monthly mini-builds. Models you can build in-store to take home. Subject to age restrictions.

Comment: Not to forget all the accessories: clothes, outfits, watches, magnets, clocks, torches, etc.