# Obtaining LEGO blocks

Tags: piece-information, shopping

In the olden days, it was possible to go to the hobby store and get a box of specific capability.  Now adays, I basically see lego blocks sold as part of "action" sets.

Question: Is it still possible to get blocks of a specific type in a specific quantity?

Comment: See also: [What is the most cost effective way to get basic bricks in bulk?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/6930/56) and [Is it possible to buy a bulk of 1000s of basic bricks?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/1163/56). LEGO also sell their ["Creative Box" range](https://shop.lego.com/en-GB/Individual-Bricks) with boxes of standard elements, including some colour themes.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things I can think of.

### 1. Bricklink

Bricklink is a reputable online site. You can buy any pieces ever made by LEGO across the globe. Their site may seem hard to navigate at first, but it doesn't take much to get used to. Also, if you have any questions you can ask here.

### 2. Pick a Brick

If you live near a LEGO store you can find yourself a variety of parts. The prices are decent. Don't be afraid to fill the cup a little more than full. They have tape just for that purpose. The selection changes as they run out of parts.

### 3. Local LEGO Shops

There may be a small locally owned LEGO establishment near you. I am not talking about a supermarket like Target or Walmart. I refer to small "holes in the wall" that may have a pick a brick much like LEGO Stores.

### 4. Bricks and Pieces

This is a suggestion that I myself have not used personally. Apparently you can order any parts they allow in production in your desired quantity. I am not sure of the price, but the reliability should be there since it is from LEGO.

Answer (score 2):

Look under the "shopping" tag in this forum. You will find answers about various aspects of acquiring LEGO.