# Is there a listing of the Types of LEGO blocks?

Tags: piece-information

What are the different specific "types" of LEGO blocks that have been manufactured?  I am not talking about any of the action figures or themes.  Is there some type of list, as to type, size, colors?

Are they still available for purchase?

I was especially interested in the following that I have not seen in awhile.

1. Cylinder (1x1)
2. Beveled (various)
3. Lettered (1x1 per letter)
4. Clear Window blocks (in 1,2,4,8 stud sizes)
5. Plates
6. Blocks with a hole of a wheel and of course the wheel.
7. Partial-circle/curved parts

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9658/obtaining-lego-blocks. Visit bricklink for the total overview, and the LEGO store to see what is available today. The common words are bricks, plates, tiles, panels and so on. You will see it once you visit bricklink (or brickset or one of the other sites dedicated to LEGO).

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of sites that document all the LEGO bricks, and indeed other items they make.

Two oft-cited examples are:

- https://www.bricklink.com
- https://brickset.com

Comment: I'd suggest providing direct URL's directly to part catalogs, like https://www.bricklink.com/catalogTree.asp?itemType=P&itemBrand=1000 for BL and https://rebrickable.com/parts/ for Rebrickable instead of Brickset. Brickset doesn't really have good part catalog.